# RMarkdown error in YAML

Tags: yaml, rstudio, r-markdown

I watched a great webinar by RStudio the other day about RMarkdown.  After the webinar they posted the code used in the demonstrations online and I wanted to check out one example. I took [their code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/webinars/master/2014-01/4-linked-brush.Rmd), put it in my RStudio (which says it's fully up-to-date, v0.98.978), installed or updated all the necessary packages and hit "Run Document"

I receive an error which I do not understand and for which Google has been very unhelpful.   What is this mysterious <document start> and how do I include it?  I assumed all necessary components would be included given the source of the code.

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(front_matter) : 
  Parser error: did not find expected <document start> at line 2, column 1
Calls: <Anonymous> -> parse_yaml_front_matter -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue came from copying the code from the browser to Rstudio.

The original header information was:

```
---
title: "Linked brushing"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```

the pasted text was:

```
---
  title: "Linked brushing"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```

The missing <document start> was an unequal amount of white space before each element of the header.  This can be fixed by adding white space to the 'output' and 'runtime' lines or by removing the white space of the 'title' line.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution is not applicable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64056894/error-in-yamlyaml-load-eval-expr-true-when-using-shiny-in-rmarkdown

Answer (score 5):

Another frequent cause of this error message is using tabs instead of spaces to indent your YAML code. You can only use SPACES to indent YAML, not TABS. I am writing this for my future self to find here.

```
title: "Initial Results"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the case but the same type of error can occur when using `pkgdown::build_site` or, more viciously, `pkgdown::build_article`. When using the latter to build a specific vignette for a package, I noticed that internally the headers of all the vignettes are parsed. Therefore, even if the specific vignette you are building is correct, the error occurs without specification of which file's header is corrupt. So, you might find yourself struggling to debug a header which is in fact correct, when the problem  is in another file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to add a single space after the three dashes at the top of the YAML header:

> ---[single space here -without the squared brackets]
> title: "Linked brushing" 
> output: html_document
> runtime: shiny

---

Answer (score -1):

Delete a file from the directory may cause a similar problem as well. Yaml, markdown, knitr should be reinstall after removing from where ever it is located .../R/library.