# Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : when using shiny in Rmarkdown

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, knitr

I can't compile any .Rmd document with shiny. For example, this five-line document (or any document, e.g. the one created with File->New File -> R Markdown ... : Shiny Document)

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---
End of my very short document.
```

I get this error when I click on "Run Document" button:

```
==> rmarkdown::run('/home/gxd/R-codes/lesson10/tmp.Rmd', shiny_args = list(launch.browser = FALSE), auto_reload = FALSE, dir = '/home/gxd/R-codes/lesson10',  render_args = list(encoding = 'UTF-8'));
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a quoted scalar at line 2, column 8 found unexpected end of stream at line 8, column 15
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Following this advise:
[RMarkdown error in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382459/rmarkdown-error-in-yaml)
I checked for all spaces and other special symbols in YAML header. All seems correct.

Anyone knows what causes it and how to fix it? My session info below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
...
>   packageVersion("shiny") 
[1] ‘1.5.0’
>   packageVersion("rmarkdown") 
[1] ‘2.3’
>   packageVersion("knitr") 
[1] ‘1.28’
```

Comment: Not reproducible for me. In any case, I suggest you update your R and RStudio.

Comment: very odd, I got this error when having a context: setup parameter on a r code chunk.

Comment: actually, scrap that, same error when I have `echo:false` in a qmd file r chunk. I.e. I miss out the space between `echo:` and `false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that if I create New Project, and then I create a new R Markdown file with Shiny, then it compiled just fine.

I must be something that was in my previous project directory that was preventing from compiling my .Rmd with file with shiny. I do have plenty of other files there  (including other .Rmd with shiny, none of which compiled) and various sub-directories (where I also have .Rmd files with shiny, and where they DO compile).

But I still have not figured what exactly was causing the problem. I tried to delete ./Rproj.user and .Rhistory - it did not have any effect.

So I've created a new clean directory and put my simple 5 line .Rmd file shown above and it compiled.

I'm still very curious to understand what was the problem...

UPDATE:
Now I know where the problem was! -
In the same directory I had another unrelated "unfinished" .Rmd file.
This other .Rmd file had YAML header with unfinished (open) string in title:

```
title: "The Header of another Rmd file that was in the same directory
```

Note, title is missing closing `"`.

Once I fixed it, i can now compile any other .Rmd in the same directory.
But if i leave it unfixed,  I wil lnot be to compile ANY other .Rmd in the same directory!
That;s kinda strange, but that's how it is.

Comment: strange but it helped me too.

Comment: This is SO WEIRD but also worked for me. In my case, it was an unresolved merge conflict >>>>>> line inside of a completely separate .Rmd file