# Break line and bold caption in Kable

Tags: r, kable, caption

How can I break the caption of my PDF table generated with `Kable` and turn into bold the upper part?

This is the table I generated:

[image]

And I need the title to be: bold{Producte interior brut} \breaklinehere {(% de variació interanual, llevat dels casos indicats)}

Here's the dataset and code:

```
structure(list(...1 = c("Catalunya", "PIB", "Demanda interna1", 
"Demanda externa1", "Espanya", "PIB", "Demanda interna1", "Demanda externa1", 
"Zona euro", "PIB", "Demanda interna1", "Demanda externa1", "PIB d'Alemanya", 
"PIB de França", "PIB d'Itàlia", "Internacional", "PIB de la UE-27", 
"PIB dels EUA", "PIB del Japó"), `2020` = c(NA, -11.9, -7.4, 
-4.5, NA, -11.2, -9, -2.2, NA, -6.1, -5.57, -0.53, -3.8, -7.5, 
-9, NA, -5.6, -2.2, -4.3), `2021` = c(NA, 6.2, 3.8, 2.4, NA, 
6.4, 5.9, 0.5, NA, 5.6, 4.24, 1.36, 3.2, 6.4, 8.3, NA, 5.7, 5.8, 
2.1), `2022` = c(NA, 5.5, 2.7, 2.8, NA, 5.5, 5.12183164381576, 
0.378168356184236, NA, 3.6, 3.76, -0.16, 1.8, 2.5, 3.7, NA, 3.5, 
1.9, 1.1), `1r 2023` = c(NA, 3.2, 1.1, 2.1, NA, 4.1, 1.3, 2.8, 
NA, 1.2, 0.63, 0.57, -0.2, 1, 2.1, NA, 1.1, 1.71772942152937, 
2), `2n 2023` = c(NA, 2.1, 1.2, 0.9, NA, 2, 2.2, -0.2, NA, 0.5, 
0.46, 0.04, 0.1, 1.1, 0.3, NA, 0.4, 2.38237207285343, 1.7), `3r 2023` = c(NA, 
2.1, NA, NA, NA, 1.8, 1.6, 0.2, NA, 0.1, NA, NA, -0.4, 0.7, 0, 
NA, 0.1, 3, 1.2)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Table:

```
p3_1 <- read_xlsx("G:/SUBDIRECCIO-ESTUDIS/CONJUNTURA/INDICADORS MENSUALS/Automatitzacio_IC/proves R/IC_fitxer_RECULL_Maria.xlsx",
                  range = "B5:M24", 1, col_types = c("text", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")) [, -c(2,4,5,7,9)] 


    options(knitr.kable.NA = "-")
    
    
    grp_nm <- c("Catalunya", "Espanya", "Zona euro", "Internacional")
    
    p3_1 <- 
      p3_1 %>% 
      mutate(grp = ifelse(...1 %in% grp_nm, ...1, NA),
             ...1 = case_when(str_detect(...1, "interna1") ~ "$\\text{Demanda interna}^1$",
                              str_detect(...1, "externa1") ~ "$\\text{Demanda externa}^1$",
                              TRUE ~ ...1))%>%
      fill(grp) %>% 
      filter(!...1 %in% grp_nm) %>% 
      select(grp, everything())
      
    
    kable(p3_1[, -1],
          align = "lrrrrrr",
          col.names = c("", names(p3_1[-(1:2)])),
          booktabs=TRUE,
          digits=1,
          format.args = list(big.mark="."),
          linesep = "" ,
          caption="Producte interior brut (\\% de variació interanual, llevat dels casos indicats)", escape = FALSE) %>%
      add_header_above(c("", "Any" = 3, "Trimestre" = 3), bold=T) %>%
      kable_styling(latex_options=c("HOLD_position","scale_down"), position="center") %>% 
      column_spec(1, width="4cm") %>% 
      column_spec(2:7, width="2cm") %>% 
      row_spec(0, bold = T) %>% 
      pack_rows(index = table(p3_1$grp), background = "#E0E0E0", latex_gap_space = "0pt") %>%
      footnote(general="Idescat; Eurostat; INE; BEA; ESRI; Agència Estatal d'Administració Tributària.", general_title = "Font:", footnote_as_chunk = T,)  %>%
      footnote(general="$^{A}$Dada avançada. $^{1}$Contribució al creixement. $^{2}$Sèrie original corregida d'efectes de calendari.
               $^{3}$En valors constants. Exclou estacions de servei.",  escape = F, general_title = "Nota:", threeparttable = TRUE, footnote_as_chunk = T,)
```

yaml:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: no
    toc: no
    toc_depth: 3
    df_print: paged
    fig_caption: yes
header-includes: 
    \usepackage{booktabs} 
    \usepackage{floatrow} 
    \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
    \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
    \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
    \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
```

Comment: The styling of your figure caption is probably controlled by LaTeX – for example, have a look at the `caption` package (in LaTeX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate the errors you mention in the comments to the answer with a minimal example.

However, using your data and code in the question this seems to work.

The main differences are:

1. use `kbl` not `kable`
2. use `\newline` rather than `\\\\`
3. change in the approach to making only the first part of the caption bold using latex `textbf{...}`.

   ```
   ---
    output:
      pdf_document:
        number_sections: no
        toc: no
        toc_depth: 3
        df_print: paged
        fig_caption: yes
    header-includes: 
        \usepackage{booktabs} 
        \usepackage{floatrow} 
        \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
        \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
        \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
        \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption} 

    ---
   ```

   ```
   library(kableExtra)
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr)
   library(stringr)
   ```

   ```
   # Note I have changed the cedilla in França to a c

   p3_1 <- 
     structure(list(...1 = c("Catalunya", "PIB", "Demanda interna1", 
   "Demanda externa1", "Espanya", "PIB", "Demanda interna1", "Demanda externa1", 
   "Zona euro", "PIB", "Demanda interna1", "Demanda externa1", "PIB d'Alemanya", 
   "PIB de Franca", "PIB d'Itàlia", "Internacional", "PIB de la UE-27", 
   "PIB dels EUA", "PIB del Japó"), `2020` = c(NA, -11.9, -7.4, 
   -4.5, NA, -11.2, -9, -2.2, NA, -6.1, -5.57, -0.53, -3.8, -7.5, 
   -9, NA, -5.6, -2.2, -4.3), `2021` = c(NA, 6.2, 3.8, 2.4, NA, 
   6.4, 5.9, 0.5, NA, 5.6, 4.24, 1.36, 3.2, 6.4, 8.3, NA, 5.7, 5.8, 
   2.1), `2022` = c(NA, 5.5, 2.7, 2.8, NA, 5.5, 5.12183164381576, 
   0.378168356184236, NA, 3.6, 3.76, -0.16, 1.8, 2.5, 3.7, NA, 3.5, 
   1.9, 1.1), `1r 2023` = c(NA, 3.2, 1.1, 2.1, NA, 4.1, 1.3, 2.8, 
   NA, 1.2, 0.63, 0.57, -0.2, 1, 2.1, NA, 1.1, 1.71772942152937, 
   2), `2n 2023` = c(NA, 2.1, 1.2, 0.9, NA, 2, 2.2, -0.2, NA, 0.5, 
   0.46, 0.04, 0.1, 1.1, 0.3, NA, 0.4, 2.38237207285343, 1.7), `3r 2023` = c(NA, 
   2.1, NA, NA, NA, 1.8, 1.6, 0.2, NA, 0.1, NA, NA, -0.4, 0.7, 0, 
   NA, 0.1, 3, 1.2)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
   "tbl", "data.frame"))
   ```

   ```
       options(knitr.kable.NA = "-")


       grp_nm <- c("Catalunya", "Espanya", "Zona euro", "Internacional")

       p3_1 <- 
         p3_1 |> 
         mutate(grp = ifelse(...1 %in% grp_nm, ...1, NA),
                ...1 = case_when(str_detect(...1, "interna1") ~ "$\\text{Demanda interna}^1$",
                                 str_detect(...1, "externa1") ~ "$\\text{Demanda externa}^1$",
                                 TRUE ~ ...1))|>
         fill(grp) |> 
         filter(!...1 %in% grp_nm) |> 
         select(grp, everything())


       kbl(p3_1[, -1],
             align = "lrrrrrr",
             col.names = c("", names(p3_1[-(1:2)])),
             booktabs=TRUE,
             digits=1,
             format.args = list(big.mark="."),
             linesep = "" ,
             caption="\\textbf{Producte interior brut} \\newline (\\% de variació interanual, llevat dels casos indicats)", 
           escape = FALSE) |>
         add_header_above(c("", "Any" = 3, "Trimestre" = 3), bold=T) |>
         kable_styling(latex_options=c("HOLD_position","scale_down"), position="center") |> 
         column_spec(1, width="4cm") |> 
         column_spec(2:7, width="2cm") |> 
         row_spec(0, bold = T) |> 
         pack_rows(index = table(p3_1$grp), background = "#E0E0E0", latex_gap_space = "0pt") |>
         footnote(general="Idescat; Eurostat; INE; BEA; ESRI; Agència Estatal d'Administració Tributària.", general_title = "Font:")  |>
         footnote(general="$^{A}$Dada avançada. $^{1}$Contribució al creixement. $^{2}$Sèrie original corregida d'efectes de calendari.
                  $^{3}$En valors constants. Exclou estacions de servei.",  escape = F, general_title = "Nota:", threeparttable = TRUE)
   ```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @dufei suggests this can be done with setting arguments of the LaTeX caption package. For example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[font={bf}]{caption} 
  
---

```{r}

library(kableExtra)

    kbl(mtcars[1:3, 1:4],
        caption="Caption in bold. \\\\ With a line break for a second line",
        booktabs = TRUE)

```
````

The line break is achieved by using LaTeX `\\`; each backslash needs to be escaped hence `\\\\` in the code.

Note the caption package defaults to centring the caption. There are arguments which allow for justification and indentation of the caption if that is preferable. Also the caption package allows you to edit the label and text of the caption separately if you want.

[image]

Following OP comment: first line in bold with the second line in plain text can be achieved with...

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[font={normalfont}]{caption} 
---

```{r}

    kbl(mtcars[1:3, 1:4],
        caption="\\textbf{Caption in bold.} \\\\ With a line break for a second plain text line",
        booktabs = TRUE)

```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. And is there any way to make only the upper part bold?

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 17, column 5
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Comment: Without seeing how your yaml is written its hard to tell, its usually because the spacing is incorrect or using tabs rather than spaces. Have a look at related problems on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382459/rmarkdown-error-in-yaml or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ymlthis/vignettes/yaml-overview.html which explains how yaml should be set up.

Comment: Okey, I will have a look. And is it possible to make bold only the first part of the caption?

Comment: Caption in bold (but in this case it doesn't matter since I am not enumerating tables)

Comment: The \\\\ is not working (I don't get a line break but an error)

Comment: I've just added the header-includes to my question. Then I get this error: Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 17, column 5
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted